# Inventory management in Rails

Tags: database-design, rails

I'm creating a inventory management app in rails. I have an `User` Table and a `Recipe` table, there is also some tables with types of material (pens, sharpies, paper, and so on). Because there is a lot of types of paper, pens and other things, and every user may want a diferent pen, but a pen I think that it will be better to have a type of article and have in the `Recipe` table the Quantity of articles needed. So when an user checks his list of articles there will be Pens: 2  and maybe some options and a search for more info of an specific pen. Like a ToDo list. But I having trouble to figure out the relationships of the tables for this purpose. Right now im designing the database. I was thinking in use MySQL in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put 'on paper' what you 'fields' that you need. Once you have that then you must group them based on what fields have a same identifier. In you case you might have 3 entities:

1. `User` with an *ID* and a *name*
2. `Group` with an *ID* and a *name* (with values like like **pen** and **paper**)
3. `Material` with an *ID*, the *GroupID* and a *name*

For the **ToDo** you can try yourself to figure it out.

Google on *database normalisation* to find some more information. You do not need to go down all the way but try to figure out the first 3 forms.